# What will I see after I kill the /sbin/init?

Tags: init, kill

What will happen after I killed `/sbin/init` (PID:1)?

Will the system crash after this?

Comment: You can't. You will get an error message "Attempt to kill init".

Comment: Why don't you try and see?

Comment: @muru haha,good idea 

Comment: It is a good idea. It takes, what, 10 minutes to spin up a VM and run the command.

Comment: @muru I have a ubuntu machine to test so it is no need to run a VM.

Answer (score 4):

> PID 1 (init) is the exception to the usual signal-related rules.
> Here’s what Linux manual (man 2 kill) says about it:
>
> The only signals that can be sent to process ID 1, the init process,
> are those for which init has explicitly installed signal handlers.
> This is done to assure the system is not brought down accidentally.
>
> Since it’s impossible to set a handler for SIGKILL, a SIGKILL would
> never be delivered to PID 1. The process who sends the signal,
> however, would get 0 return code, indicating that everything went
> fine.
>
> In fact killing PID 1, if it were allowed, would cause disaster,
> because it’s the ancestor process of all the other processes, and
> there’d be be nowhere to re-parent them to. If PID 1 calls exit()
> itself, the Linux kernel would panic, that is, immediately abort
> everything and print a stack trace, like Blue Screen of Death on
> Windows. You can try this yourself by making your shell the PID 1:
>
> [image]

[Reference](https://www.quora.com/Is-it-possible-to-kill-the-init-process-in-Linux-by-the-kill-9-command)

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu 20.04, it causes the screen to freeze instantly. I'm honestly not sure if any processes keep running.

Contrary to what the other answer says, you *can* kill PID 1, by the way, just not with `kill` or an equivalent. If you bind to it with gdb (`gdb -p 1`) you can kill the process with the `kill` command.